# How can I submit a form from another page with existing data?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Edit:
I understand that its probably easiest to use jQuery's built in ajax function here, but my question now is about the names that the form is using for its fields. This is a var_dump of what the form usually submits using test values. It seems to be randomly generating the form names which makes this problematic.

```
array (size=10)
  '__CSRFToken__' => string '3bc67b3ea7645150d346c3db476c53a94ceee80e' (length=40)
  'a' => string 'open' (length=4)
  'topicId' => string '12' (length=2)
  '4d46ff92be4bf2f9' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'b6679eba951ccafb' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'de756c0f51c9b255' => string '' (length=0)
  'de756c0f51c9b255-ext' => string '' (length=0)
  '099ed5bd56c915a1' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'message' => string 'Test' (length=4)
  'draft_id' => string '4' (length=1)
```

---

On one of my web pages has users enter information to fill a ticket form. I am using osTicket to manage them but I am collecting the information on a separate page for certain reasons. Suppose I have all of the information stored in a Javascript object,

```
var ticket = {
    name : "John Snow",
    email : "test@gmail.com",
    summary: "xxx",
    body: "xxxx"
};
```

for example, how could I go about getting that information to the form on the other page ( picture below ) and submit it? 
[image]

Comment: Make use of `cURL` in PHP. [`Manual`](http://in3.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: `<form action="page.php[or whatever]">` If you want to use html and the <form> tag

Comment: Just to clarify: You have an array of form values on "page1", and you want to put it into the form on "page2" and submit it?

Comment: Yes Sverri, that is correct. I don't need to even see the form on page 2, it just needs to be submitted.

Comment: The easiest way to solve this would be to send the array's data to the URL that the form points to (i.e. the `action="..."` URL). It can be done using plain Javascript but using jQuery's AJAX module would make it much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit form by various methods by using html form tag ,jquery etc.I m giving example with jquery.
Script:

```
   $('#submitButn').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Index",  //url for your page,
        type: "POST",
        data: dataToPost //you data which u want to post
        success: function (data, status) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
            alert("error");
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay I understand how I would use ajax for this but I am now having trouble figuring out what names I need to post data for. The page I am trying to send to is not very easy to follow. `<input type="text" name="de756c0f51c9b255" value=""/>` There is tons of stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax with something like this:

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhReq.open("GET", "page.php?name=name&emailemail&etc...", false);
 xhReq.send(null);
 var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
 alert(serverResponse); // Shows "15"
```

You should read this for a better explanation [AJAX](http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call)